# Program in the Program Files folder unable to create files in it's own directory

Tags: windows, windows-7, administrator

This is my first time asking a question on superuser (although I refer to stack-overflow and superuser frequently), so bear with me if I make any mistakes or am unclear in my question, and I will fix any errors or clarify as needed.

I've developed an application, say MyApp, and created an installer that installs the main executable with its related dependencies (folders and files) into its very own dedicated folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAppFolder\`.

The problem is that during runtime it is supposed to create files like logs and more in its own directory, the `MyAppFolder` folder. After some digging I figured it's because it's not running as administrator (my user is an admin fyi) - or rather, it is because only administrators can write to `\Program Files`, I suppose. If I run my application as administrator it's able to write the required files and folders.

But shouldn't an app ideally be able to write in its own folder? Even if it isn't running on admin privileges? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the full permissions on the folder?

Comment: And for users? ...

Comment: "But shouldn't an app ideally be able to write in its own folder?" - No; Writing a user's application to the installation directory is not following best practices. Your application CAN write to it's directory, but since you are attempting to write that data to a protected folder, it cannot write to that particular directory without elevated permissions.  Everything you describe is perfectly normal. Best practices calls for user specific data to be written to %AppData% instead.  However, how you properly design an application, is a extremely broad topic.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh I see, I will use the AppData folder then, for that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @PCnoob - %LocalAppData% is also acceptable.  Google, Firefox, Edge, Teams all write data to a directory.  Your application is responsible for the creation of the folder obviously.

Comment: @PCnoob All ACLs for `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyAppFolder` and files/subfolders within it  are inherited from `%ProgramFiles%`||`%ProgramFiles(x86)%` - e.g. [`icacls %ProgramFiles(x86)%\gpg4win`](https://imgur.com/a/7BE4Pmr). For clarification, `%UserProfile%\AppData` shouldn't be written to, either `%AppData%` or `%LocalAppData%` would be written to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept in Windows as a "program's own folder".

The concept that exists is "program's current folder", which by default
is the folder from which it was run. The permissions that the program
possesses come from the user account that launched it, not from where
it is situated.

This means that when the program executes from Program Files, it is by
default running under your account and by default not as Admin.
So it doesn't have the permission to write in the folder where
it happens to be located.

It would make sense for the program to write its file(s) in a non-protected
folder. The usual place is to create your own folder inside
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local`, also available in the environment
variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, but this can be anywhere you choose.